# Subscripting a string in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, string, subscript

I have a data in the object `section_data.title` and i am trying to use `str.sup()` where `str=section_data.title;` and `str` holds following data:

> str="Not less than 30 net **ft2** (2.8 net **m2**) per patient in a
>   hospital or nursing    home, or not less than 15 net **ft2** (1.4 net
>   **m2**) per resident in a limited care facility, shall be provided within the aggregated area of corridors, patient rooms, treatment
>   rooms, lounge or dining areas, and other similar areas on each side of
>   the horizontal exit. On stories not housing bed or litterborne
>   patients, not less than 6 net **ft2** (0.56 net **m2**) per occupant
>   shall be provided on each side of the horizontal exit for the total
>   number of occupants in adjoining compartments."

Now I want to add superscript for the bold words indicated above (e.g **ft2**). How can I do this using `str.sup()` or are there any other alternative method to do `so in javascript?` Or any other tricks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String in javascript is not formatted. You can only do that when you output to HTML. So basically you must write it like this

```
var str = "Not less than 30 net ft<sup>2</sup> (2.8 net m<sup>2</sup>)";
document.write(str);
```

You can do a find and replace for all string contain `ft2` and `m2` turn them into `ft<sup>2</sup>` and `m<sup>2</sup>`

```
str.replace(/ft2/g,"ft<sup>2</sup>");  //But it not safe...
```

Comment: Why you are saying that it's not safe? Can you explain?

Comment: Because you may accident replace some other string as well.